# PDO bind_param is undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm moving away from mysql and mysqli as many users on stackoverflow are constantly saying good things about it.

I've made a database class and have tested this, this connects fine to the database. I've tried to update my prepared statements to match however I am in unfamiliar territory and have ended up getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in E:\xampp\htdocs\imanage\insert.php on line 50`

which reflects this line:

`$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);`

Also in regards to this I am getting the database connection success and close statements returned to me as well as the fatal error e.g:

`Successfully connected to the database!Successfully connected to the database!Successfully disconnected from the database!`

I'll explain what I am trying to achieve:

- Check e-mail exists in the database before registrating user
- if so tell user that this e-mail exists
- if no match insert the user into the users table and encrypt the password

The relevant code is below and would appreciate if anyone could give me some guidance on this.

index.php

```
        <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="class.Login.php">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"></form>
```

insert.php

```
public function insert() {

                    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($email_count);
                    $stmt->fetch();//fecth
                    $stmt->close();     

                    if ($email_count > 0) {
                        echo "email exisits! click here to try <a href='register'>again</a>";
                        } else {
                            //escape the POST data for added protection
                            $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
                            $cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);
                            $password = $cryptedPassword;
                            $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
                            $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
                            $stmta = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            //var_dump($this->pdo->error);
                            $stmta->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $name, $email); // bind strings to the paramater

                                /* execute prepared statement */
                                $stmta->execute();
                                printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmta->affected_rows);
                                /* close statement and connection */
                                $stmta->close();
                } // end email_count and insert to table
            } // end function
```

connect/class.Database.php

```
<?php

// Database connection PDO

class Database {

    public function __construct() {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'imanage';
        $user   = 'root';
        $pass   = '';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

     public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->pdo = null;
        echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }


}

$run = new Database();
?>
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)? You're expecting PDO to work like `mysqi`. Also, why are you writing your own ORM when there are several out there like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) which are feature-complete and tested?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Some PDO examples**

Example with Bind Parameter

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Example with array

```
$data = array($username, $password, $name, $email); 
$stmta = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmta->execute($data);
```

[PDO tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: Hi thanks, thats really useful, however I need to bind my result so I can call on the `$email_count` to see if it exists, I'm getting this error `Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result()` how do I do this with PDO? @Sbml +1 btw

Comment: You could use fetchColumn() with your query SELECT COUNT(*) to return the column count. For example: if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) { DO SOMETHING }

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sbml You are a genius.

Answer (score 12):

set `bind_param()` to `bindParam()`.